# Site downtime becuase of gunicron cpu utilization is 96%

Tags: python-3.x, django, devops, gunicorn, autoscaling

We have Django application that run with gunicorn. We ware facing site downtime because of high trafic. Gunicorn is utilizng 96 % of the cpu that what cauing the issue.

Our system specification:
8 GB ram, 4 cpu

1. How to setup gunicron in such way that it can handle more than 100 request per second ?
2. What are the system specifcation required for handling 100 request per second ?
3. Is gunicorn workers are cpu count ?

Comment: There is no one-size-fits-all answer for performance issues in an arbitrary web app, there are multiple factors that affect performance and without knowing what your app does or seeing the code it's almost impossible to give advice. Optimise badly written code, add more servers?

Answer (score 1):

Keep one worker only and increase number of threads in that worker. or use something like gevent in gunicorn